# How can I write the concatenated string to the given string pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am having trouble with the very last line in my function, where I am stilly learning the basics of C. I have the signature of this function given and am tasked to write a function to concatenate two strings. The commented line outputs the correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// 1) len = dst-len + max_dst_len

int strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, int max_dst_len) {
    int len = 0;

    while (dst[len] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }

    int total_len = len + max_dst_len;

    char *new_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * total_len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        new_str[i] = dst[i];
    }

    for (int i = len; i < total_len; i++) {
        new_str[i] = src[i - len];
    }

    new_str[total_len] = '\0';

    //printf("%s <--\n", new_str);

    dst = *new_str;

    return total_len;

}

int main() {
    char test1[] = "dst";
    char test1src[] = "src";
    printf("%s\n", test1);
    printf("%d\n", strlcat(test1, test1src, 10));
    printf("%s\n", test1);
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for any memory allocation in this function. If you find yourself `malloc`-ing, you're already off the rails. The max size last argument (which you're currently using to lie to your function, claiming `dst` can hold 10 char when it can't) dictates the max occupancy of the target buffer, including the terminator. Your function should use that info; no dynamic allocation should be used here.

Comment: Are you prohibited from using `strlen()`?

Comment: Your destination buffer `test1` is not long enough to contain "dstsrc".

Comment: `char test1[] = "dst";` is the same as `test1[4] = "dst";`. `test1` can only hold 4 chars, so `strlcat(test1, test1src, 10)` does not make much sense.  I would expect to see `strlcat(test1, test1src, sizeof test1)` or `strlcat(test1, test1src, N)` where N is no larger than 4 (or 3 depending on the implementation of strlcat).  You cannot put a string where it does not fit.  Arrays do not grow.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding `max_dst_len` to the length of `dst`. `max_dst_len` is the amount of memory that's already allocated in `dst`, you need to ensure that the concatenated string doesn't exceed this length.

So you need to *subtract* `len` from `max_dst_len`, and also subtract 1 to allow room for the null byte. This will tell you the maximum number of bytes you can copy from `src` to the end of `dst`.

In your `main()` code, you need to declare `test1` to be at least `10` bytes if you pass `10` as the `max_dst_len` argument. When you omit the size in the array declaration, it sizes the array just big enough to hold the string you use to initialize it. It's best to use `sizeof test1` as this argument, to ensure that it's correct for the string you're concatenating to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, int max_dst_len) {
    int len = 0;
    while (dst[len] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }

    int len_to_copy = max_dst_len - len - 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len_to_copy && src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        dst[len+i] = src[i];
    }
    dst[i] = '\0';

    //printf("%s <--\n", new_str);

    return i + len;

}

int main() {
    char test1[6] = "dst";
    char test1src[] = "src";
    printf("%s\n", test1);
    printf("%d\n", strlcat(test1, test1src, sizeof test1));
    printf("%s\n", test1);
}
```